# Slim Framework with Paris / Idiorm / Twig - How to handle Fileuploads?

Tags: php, file-upload, twig, slim

Jep, thats the Question. How to handle Fileuplaods via this nice Team?

Something like:

```
$app -> post('/new/', function() use ($app) {
    $photo = Model::factory('Photos') -> create();      
    $unique_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $WORKSPACE = 'data/photos/';
    $media = $HTTP_POST_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $filetype = strrchr($media,'.');
    $new_upload = $WORKSPACE . $unique_id . $filetype;
    $the_upload = copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $new_upload);
    $uploaded_file   = $new_upload;
    @chmod($uploaded_file, 0777);

    $photo -> timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $photo -> url = 'data/photos/' . $unique_id . $filetype;
    $photo -> new_picture = $unique_id . $filetype;
    $photo -> description = $app -> request() -> post('description');
    $photo -> save();
    $app -> redirect('/upload/');
});
```

Will not work, cause:

Slim Application Error:
Message: Undefined variable: HTTP_POST_FILES

But how can i access a fileupload field like:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" value="" id="photo" />
```

via Slim?

Comment: Maybe use $_FILES instead of $HTTP_POST_FILES

Answer (score 4):

`$HTTP_POST_FILES` is not a superglobal. It is out of the scope of your function.

You should use [**$_FILES**](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) instead, also because `$HTTP_POST_FILES` is deprecated.